# Singleton LocationManager starting updates?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, singleton, cllocationmanager

Why is this CLLocationManager inside my singleton not working?  I took this code  http://jinru.wordpress.com/2010/08/15/singletons-in-objective-c-an-example-of-cllocationmanager/

Not altertering his code at all (so if I should add something to his code let me know) its my first singleton ever.

```
- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager {

    if (locationManager != nil) {
        return [LocationController sharedInstance].locationManager;
    }

    self.locationManager = [LocationController sharedInstance];
    [LocationController sharedInstance].locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters;


    return [LocationController sharedInstance].locationManager;
}
```

- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];

  ```
  // Start the location manager.
  [LocationController sharedInstance].delegate = self;
  //[[self locationManager] startUpdatingLocation];

  [[LocationController sharedInstance].locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
  ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you want to achieve in your - (CLLocationManager *)locationManager method here. But in the init function in LocationController.h, you should add something like this:

```
- (id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self != nil) {
       self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
       self.locationManager.delegate = self;
       self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    }
   return self;
}
```

And when you want to call the singleton object in other controller to update the location, you should be able to just call:

```
        [[LocationController sharedInstance].locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Remember to also implement the delegate method - (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation*)location in your controller.

Hope it helps this time if my post didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem is in the delegate. This points to the file, not the singleton.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `- (CLLocationManager *)locationManager` is a method of `LocationController` the line

```
self.locationManager = [LocationController sharedInstance];
```

makes no sense as you assign the singleton instance of LocationController to `self.locationManager` which is of type `CLLocationManager`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did and you can find the complete example on `github`.

https://github.com/irfanlone/CLLocationManager-Singleton-Swift